# L'Hôpital's rule when lim f′(x)/g′(x) → ±∞

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, divergence-operator

If lim f′(x)/g′(x) → ±∞ does lim f(x)/g(x) → ±∞ as well? I've read about L'Hôpital's rule only working when the limit of the derivatives exists but I recently stumbled upon some text that indicated that it worked when it diverges to infinity, is that true?

Comment: Yes it is true. Most statements of L'Hospital's rule fail to mention this. But it works for the case when limit is $\pm\infty$.